# UIDatePicker set Maximum date

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using this code to block the user from going over the limit I set:

in view did load:

```
NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
[DatePickerForDate setMinimumDate:Date];
[DatePickerForDate setMaximumDate:[Date dateByAddingTimeInterval: 63072000]]; //time interval in seconds
```

And this method:

```
- (IBAction)datePickerChanged:(id)sender{
if ( [DatePickerForDate.date timeIntervalSinceNow ] < 0 ){
    NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
    DatePickerForDate.date = Date;
}

if ( [DatePickerForDate.date timeIntervalSinceNow ] > 63072000){
    NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
    DatePickerForDate.date = Date;
}
}
```

The first part works (the one with <0), and returns to the current date, but the one > 63072000, sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. By the way 63072000 is about 2 years. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experimented using a UIDatePicker with a maximumDate of one month from now:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date] ;
// Get current NSDate without seconds & milliseconds, so that I can better compare the chosen date to the minimum & maximum dates.
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents* nowWithoutSecondsComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:now] ;
NSDate* nowWithoutSeconds = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowWithoutSecondsComponents] ;
//  UIDatePicker* picker ;
picker.minimumDate = nowWithoutSeconds ;

NSDateComponents* addOneMonthComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
addOneMonthComponents.month = 1 ;
NSDate* oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:addOneMonthComponents toDate:nowWithoutSeconds options:0] ;
picker.maximumDate = oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds ;
```

I found that:

- The first time you attempt to select a date outside of the minimum and maximum range, the UIDatePicker will scroll itself back "in range".
- If you immediately select a date out of range again, the Picker will not scroll back, allowing you to select a date out of range.
- If the Picker's selected date is out of range, its `date` property will return the nearest date that's in range.
- When you call `setDate:` or `setDate:animated:`, if the date you pass is the exact same date returned by the Picker's `date` property, the Picker will do nothing.

With that in mind, here is a method that you can call when the Picker's value changes that prevents you from ever selecting a date out of range:

```
- (IBAction) datePickerChanged:(id)sender {
    // When `setDate:` is called, if the passed date argument exactly matches the Picker's date property's value, the Picker will do nothing. So, offset the passed date argument by one second, ensuring the Picker scrolls every time.
    NSDate* oneSecondAfterPickersDate = [picker.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1] ;
    if ( [picker.date compare:picker.minimumDate] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        NSLog(@"date is at or below the minimum") ;
        picker.date = oneSecondAfterPickersDate ;
    }
    else if ( [picker.date compare:picker.maximumDate] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        NSLog(@"date is at or above the maximum") ;
        picker.date = oneSecondAfterPickersDate ;
    }
}
```

The above `if` and `else if` sections are nearly identical, but I kept them separate so that I could see the different NSLogs, and also to better debug.

[Here's the working project](https://github.com/JohnSauer/Date_Picker_Always_Stay_In_Bounds) on GitHub.

Comment: I canged my IBAction with your code changing the picker to  DatePickerForDate, but for some reason the code is the if statement is never called. I never see the Logs and it has no efferct on the picker. why?

Comment: Are you positive that the code is being run whenever DatePickerForDate's value changes? If you put a simple NSLog statement before the `if ( [picker.date...` statement, you'll know for sure.

Comment: yes, the code is always called, and sorry but usually users answer and then disappear so I posted a separate question

Comment: See my last edit. I just posted my Xcode project on GitHub as a working example of a UIDatePicker that always stays within the minimumDate & maximumDate.

Comment: ...apart from the fact that I set the picker to date in the user interface because I don't need the time, the two are identical...

Comment: and that I use @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *DatePickerForDate;

Comment: and that I set the min and max like this: NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
    [DatePickerForDate setMinimumDate:Date];
    [DatePickerForDate setMaximumDate:[Date dateByAddingTimeInterval: 63072000]]; //time interval in seconds

Comment: but if I paste your code and change the mode to date and time, it works! Even if I need only date

Comment: Does that mean you're on your way to solving it?

Comment: ok, so I am using your code in the date only format, and it works, with addOneMonthComponents.month = 1; , but since I want 2 years, I put addOneMonthComponents.month = 24; and it doesn't work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23993/discussion-between-john-sauer-and-user2014474)

Comment: I think it's better to init NSCalendar using gregorian calendar, in case the user device setting using another calendar system. So, use [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; instead