# UIPicker set date Range

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDatePicker set Maximum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694452/uidatepicker-set-maximum-date)

I am using this code to block the user from going over the limit I set:

in view did load:

```
NSDate *Date=[NSDate date];
[DatePickerForDate setMinimumDate:Date];
[DatePickerForDate setMaximumDate:[Date dateByAddingTimeInterval: 63072000]]; //time interval in seconds
```

And this method:

```
- (IBAction)datePickerChanged:(id)sender{
// When `setDate:` is called, if the passed date argument exactly matches the Picker's date property's value, the Picker will do nothing. So, offset the passed date argument by one second, ensuring the Picker scrolls every time.
NSDate* oneSecondAfterPickersDate = [DatePickerForDate.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1] ;
if ( [DatePickerForDate.date compare:DatePickerForDate.minimumDate] == NSOrderedSame ) {
    NSLog(@"date is at or below the minimum") ;
    DatePickerForDate.date = oneSecondAfterPickersDate ;
}
else if ( [DatePickerForDate.date compare:DatePickerForDate.maximumDate] == NSOrderedSame   ) {
    NSLog(@"date is at or above the maximum") ;
    DatePickerForDate.date = oneSecondAfterPickersDate ;
}
}
```

The code in the if statements is never called. Why?

Comment: Try printing the dates you are retrieving in some NSLogs and see if you can determine what is going on, why it might be failing the comparison.

Comment: when I print the dates, I get the date shown on the UIDatePicker, depending on the format (yyyy...)

Comment: And the min and max dates are market. the dates out of the range are greyed out

Comment: How about using isEqualToDate: rather than checking the result of compare: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to finish [our discussion over here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694452/uidatepicker-set-maximum-date/14696824#14696824)

First, make sure the `datePickerChanged` is being called when DatePickerForDate's value is changed.